# How to improve this backup script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, backup

I wrote this backup script. I run `rsync`, `tar` and a dump of mysql.
I'd like to add some features like email alert or some kind of statistic.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

DATE=`date +%D-%T`
ORIGIN=/home/share/
DEST=/media/BACKUP/mercurio/
LOGFILE=log.txt
echo "=====Starting backup on $DATE =====" >> $LOGFILE
echo "==Start rsync" >> $LOGFILE 
rsync -arHu --delete --stats $ORIGIN $DEST/share >> $LOGFILE
wait
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "==rsync ok"  >> $LOGFILE
else
        echo "==rsync ko"   >> $LOGFILE
fi

echo "==Sart TAR" >> $LOGFILE
tar -czf $DEST`date +%y%m%d-%T`.tar.gz $ORIGIN
wait
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "==tar ok" >> $LOGFILE
else
        echo "==tar ko" >> $LOGFILE
fi
echo "==Start DUMP" >> $LOGFILE
mysqldump -u root -ptoor --all-databases > ${DEST}databases/`date +%Y%m%d-%k:%M`.sql
wait
if [$? -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "==dump ok" >> $LOGFILE
else 
        echo "==dump ko" >> $LOGFILE
fi
echo "=====End Bakcup=====" >> $LOGFILE
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. What kind of email alert? Statistics for what? (And what have you tried for either?)

Comment: sorry i don't have a precise idea, i think some guru here can give me some advice like "you need an email alert if backup fails" or "add auto-delete file older than 30days"

Comment: So you're asking for general best practices for backups, retention periods, and monitoring? That's a bit broad to say the least. We don't even know what kind of data you're backing up. You also need to take potential legal requirements into consideration. Practical limitations with how much storage you have available...

Comment: you're right...this is a too generic question :(
The files aren't vital for my business...i copy on this server only the file that i want to share with my colleagues. Server is configured as lamp for a simple wikimedia installation so i want to backup also mysql.

Comment: You should also redirect stderr to you log files, like `2>>`. `>>` is like `1>>` and redirects stdout only. Also use `--log-error=filename.log` for mysqldump.

Comment: probably belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I see two aspects to your question. One is “critique my script”; you can post that on [codereview.se] (be sure to read their FAQ first). Another aspects is that you're asking for design advice for a backup script. That's on-topic here, but you'll have to be a lot more precise as to where you're using the script (what's your equipment? How many users and admins are involved, with what level of sophistication? How much can you spend? …) and what you're after (what kind of statistic? Email about what? …). For that second aspect, edit your question here, and we can reopen it.

Comment: Epic topic clusure, post factum all at once and nocomment. So great thanks to senseless first posts. Special thanks to Teresa. Gilles want you to bow down, ir order to have any answer - but it's as always, that's why it's okay.